# What is the replacement for rich_edit_exists()?

Tags: plugin-development

A plugin inserts users into a database. If the user is an author, the visual editor isn't showing until the user saves their profile. I'm trying to figure out what setting isn't being added to the database and found the deprecated `rich_edit_exists()`.

Is there a replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is stored in the *user meta* table under the `rich_editing` meta key for each user.

You could one of these (untested):

1) Add it for your specific users, e.g. via

```
`add_user_meta( $user_id, 'rich_editing', 'true', true );`
```

2) Within the `wp_default_editor()` function, that determines the default editor, the `user_can_richedit()` function is applied.

It checks for `get_user_option( 'rich_editing' ) === 'true'`, among other things.

It's filterable through the `user_can_richedit` filter:

```
    /**
     * Filters whether the user can access the rich (Visual) editor.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     *
     * @param bool $wp_rich_edit Whether the user can access to the rich (Visual) editor.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'user_can_richedit', $wp_rich_edit );
```

3) Try to filter the `get_user_option( 'rich_editing' );` if it's missing.